# How to add the html tags but still keep the spaces intact?

Tags: java, regex, string, algorithm, data-structures

I am working on interview problems from http://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/Indeed-Software-Engineer-Intern-Interview-Questions-EI_IE100561.0,6_KO7,31.htm

The current problem I am doing is "The second question is searching a particular word in a string, and add "<b>" "<\b>" around the word's every appearance."

Here's my code:

```
public class AddBsAround {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          String testCase = "Don't   you love    it when you install all software and all programs";
           System.out.println(addBs(testCase, "all"));
      }
     public static String addBs(String sentence, String word) { 
          String result = "";
          String[] words = sentence.trim().split("\\s+");
           for(String wordInSentence: words) {
                  if(wordInSentence.equals(word)) {
                        result += "<b>" +word + "</b> ";
                  }  else {
                       result += wordInSentence + " "; 
                    }
            }
        return result;
      }
   }
```

The code produces essentially the correct output; that is, when passed in the testcase, it produces

> `Don't you love it when you install <b>all</b> software and <b>all</b> programs`

, avoiding the bug that the original author had, in that for search of "all" in "install", his code would produce "install".

However would the spaces be an issue though? When pass in

```
"Don't   you love    it "
```

, my code will produce "Don't you love it", or basically the sentence with just one space in between the words. Do you guys see this as an issue? I kinda do because the client might not expect this method to alter spaces. Would there be a workaround around this? I felt like I needed to use the regex to separate the words.

Comment: Ask your client if they're OK with it. Chances are, they will be, once you tell them that most HTML is formatted with just one space between words, and HTML *wouldn't render the extra spaces anyway*.

Comment: But say they weren't ok with it.(hypothetical job interview). How would you do account for that?

Comment: Just split on spaces rather than multiple spaces, this will solve your problem.

Comment: @committedandroider Ah, I didn't see that bit. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than splitting on `\\s+`, split on `\\s` -- that way, it splits on every single space instead of every group of them, and when you put them back together, the amount of spaces is preserved. The difference is that `+` tells the regex to split on one or more spaces, but without it, it's exactly a single one.

Aside from that, I'd recommend also using a `StringBuilder` to join the strings, since it's more efficient for very long ones, and you want to be the best possible, right?

It's just the one character change, but for the sake of completeness, this is your new method:

```
public static String addBs(String sentence, String word) { 
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String[] words = sentence.trim().split("\\s");
    for(String wordInSentence: words) {
      if(wordInSentence.equals(word)) {
        result.append("<b>").append(word).append("</b> ");
      }  else {
        result.append(wordInSentence).append(" "); 
      }
    }
    return result.toString();
  }
}
```

The result, using this code, is this:

```
Don't   you love    it when you install <b>all</b> software and <b>all</b> programs
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookarounds in regex:

```
public static String addBs(String sentence, String word) { 
    String result = "";
    String[] words = sentence.split("(?<!\\s)(?=\\s)");
    for(String wordInSentence: words) {
        if(wordInSentence.trim().equals(word)) {
            result += "<b>" +word + "</b> ";
        }  else {
            result += wordInSentence + " "; 
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Output:**

> `Don't    you  love     it  when  you  install <b>all</b>  software  and <b>all</b>  programs`

`(?<!\\s)` is a **negative lookbehind** which means the preceding character is not a space and `(?=\\s)` is a **positive lookahead** which means the following character is a space. [See regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/xT7wX0/1).

Comment: sorry for being a noob, but what does (?<!\\s)(?=\\s) do?

Answer (score 0):

As other people suggested, splitting using single space would be better. Just to approach it in a different way, try Java's pattern.

```
public static String addBs(String sentence, String word) { 
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.Compile(word);
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(sentence);
    return(m.replaceAll("<b>" + word + "</b>"));
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it matches the "all" in "install", which is supposed to be avoided. Change the regex to `"(?:^|\\s)(" + word + ")(?:\\s|$)"` and it should work, assuming that I remember my non-capturing groups correctly. Also, `Pattern.compile()` should be lower-case. Also, the outermost parentheses in the return statement are unnecessary